# All test Fails automatically after first @Test failure from same class

Tags: java, selenium, mobile, testng, appium

I use TestNG + Selenium + Appium.
Problem which i have is:
If the 1st @Test fails, all rest got failed automatically and execution will be stopped.

I tried to use @BecoreClass setUp instead of setting up at @Test still after first failure fails everything.

I thought that it skipping all the rest of the test because of it does not finish the process in the right way ( quitting an application ) that`s why i added @Aftermethod with driver.quit that it will execute it after failed method.
But still after 1st failure it automatically Fails all the tests.

I need to have multiple @Test with a test methods, which will be individual with separate configurations. And if 1st one fails, it will continue execute the rest of @Test ( even if they are from the same class) and after will give me a result .

```
package foundation;


import com.pageobjects.HeaderMenu;
import config.AppConfiguration;
import config.LogIn;
import config.DesiredCapabilitiesSetup;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;


import java.io.IOException;


public class AppiumTestTest {
    private AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    private AOWebClient aoWeb;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public AppiumTestTest(AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver, AOWebClient aoWeb) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.aoWeb = aoWeb;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public AppiumTestTest() {
    }

    private SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
/*
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }
*/



    @Test
    public void checkInTest() throws Exception {

        driver = DesiredCapabilitiesSetup.startAppiumServer(
                AppConfiguration.newBuilder()
                        .setTimeSelection(false)
                        .setBirthday(true)
                        .build());
        AOWebClient aoWebClient = DesiredCapabilitiesSetup.getAOWeb();
        LogIn logIn = new LogIn(driver, aoWebClient);
        logIn.logIn();
    }




    @Test
    public void timeSelectionTest() throws Exception {

        driver = DesiredCapabilitiesSetup.startAppiumServer(
                AppConfiguration.newBuilder()
                        .setTimeSelection(true)
                        .setBirthday(true)
                        .build());
        AOWebClient aoWebClient = DesiredCapabilitiesSetup.getAOWeb();
        LogIn logIn = new LogIn(driver, aoWebClient);
        logIn.logIn();
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void afterM(){
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }


}
```

**My Desired Capabilities are:**

```
package config;

import com.pageobjects.LaunchProgress;
import com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class DesiredCapabilitiesSetup {


    //Name of Android Device
    //public static String deviceName = "TestDevice";

    // Emulator
    //public static String deviceName = "One";

    //Path of App folder
    // public static String appLink = "/Users/af185125/FoundationApp/";


    //The name of Android application with format. (.apk).
    //public static String appName = "app331.apk";


    private static final String KEY_USE_TIME_SELECTION = "useTimeSelection";
    private static final String KEY_DISABLE_BIRTHDAY = "disableBirthday";

    @BeforeClass
    public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> startAppiumServer(AppConfiguration appConfiguration) throws IOException {
// Taking App/Device/Link path from *txt file located in the project //
        /*
        String appLink = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("appConfigurations/appLink.txt"));
        String deviceName = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("appConfigurations/deviceName.txt"));
        String appName = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("appConfigurations/appName.txt"));
        */


        String appLink = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("appConfigurations/appLink.txt"));
        String deviceName = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("appConfigurations/deviceName.txt"));
        String appName = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("appConfigurations/appName.txt"));

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, deviceName);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "4000");

        String configurationString = getConfigurationString(appConfiguration);
        cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.OPTIONAL_INTENT_ARGUMENTS,"--es appium_config \"" + configurationString + "\"");

        //cap.setCapability("avd","nexus");
        File appSource = new File(appLink);
        File app = new File(appSource, appName);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());



        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);




        LaunchProgress launch = new LaunchProgress(driver);
        launch.waitForLaunchScreenToLoad();


        return driver;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static String getConfigurationString(AppConfiguration appConfiguration) {
        JSONObject configuration = new JSONObject();
        configuration.put(KEY_USE_TIME_SELECTION, appConfiguration.timeSelection);
        configuration.put(KEY_DISABLE_BIRTHDAY, appConfiguration.birthday);
        return configuration.toJSONString();
    }

}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
objc[20683]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58385', transport: 'socket'
[TestNG] Running:
  /Users/af185125/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2016.2/temp-testng-customsuite.xml

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 80.28 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'WUSAF185125-G3D', ip: '153.86.242.30', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{app=/Users/af185125/android-ui-test/currentApp/appiumT.apk, appPackage=com.ao.demo.beta, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, appWaitPackage=com.ao.demo.beta, appWaitActivity=com.ao.core.ui.launch.LaunchActivity, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=ad071603280ea0c18d, version=6.0, fullReset=true, platform=LINUX, deviceUDID=ad071603280ea0c18d, appActivity=com.ao.core.ui.launch.LaunchActivity, desired={app=/Users/af185125/android-ui-test/currentApp/appiumT.apk, newCommandTimeout=4000, platformVersion=6.0, automationName=Appium, platformName=Android, deviceName=Automation, version=6.0, optionalIntentArguments=--es appium_config "{"useTimeSelection":false,"disableBirthday":true}", fullReset=true}, newCommandTimeout=4000, platformVersion=6.0.1, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, automationName=Appium, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Android, optionalIntentArguments=--es appium_config "{"useTimeSelection":false,"disableBirthday":true}"}]
Session ID: 30270d0f-8594-4ead-b5b6-56dfeee37f44
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=fasf.com}

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:51)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:67)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:413)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementById(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:75)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementById(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementById(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:63)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at foundation.AppiumTestTest.checkInTest(AppiumTestTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:746)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)


org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 7 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'WUSAF185125-G3D', ip: '153.86.242.30', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{app=/Users/af185125/android-ui-test/currentApp/appiumT.apk, appPackage=com.ao.demo.beta, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, appWaitPackage=com.ao.demo.beta, appWaitActivity=com.ao.core.ui.launch.LaunchActivity, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=ad071603280ea0c18d, version=6.0, fullReset=true, platform=LINUX, deviceUDID=ad071603280ea0c18d, appActivity=com.ao.core.ui.launch.LaunchActivity, desired={app=/Users/af185125/android-ui-test/currentApp/appiumT.apk, newCommandTimeout=4000, platformVersion=6.0, automationName=Appium, platformName=Android, deviceName=Automation, version=6.0, optionalIntentArguments=--es appium_config "{"useTimeSelection":false,"disableBirthday":true}", fullReset=true}, newCommandTimeout=4000, platformVersion=6.0.1, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, automationName=Appium, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Android, optionalIntentArguments=--es appium_config "{"useTimeSelection":false,"disableBirthday":true}"}]
Session ID: 30270d0f-8594-4ead-b5b6-56dfeee37f44

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:51)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.close(RemoteWebDriver.java:521)
    at foundation.AppiumTestTest.afterM(AppiumTestTest.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:712)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:746)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)


Test ignored.
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 5 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'WUSAF185125-G3D', ip: '153.86.242.30', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{app=/Users/af185125/android-ui-test/currentApp/appiumT.apk, appPackage=com.ao.demo.beta, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, appWaitPackage=com.ao.demo.beta, appWaitActivity=com.ao.core.ui.launch.LaunchActivity, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=ad071603280ea0c18d, version=6.0, fullReset=true, platform=LINUX, deviceUDID=ad071603280ea0c18d, appActivity=com.ao.core.ui.launch.LaunchActivity, desired={app=/Users/af185125/android-ui-test/currentApp/appiumT.apk, newCommandTimeout=4000, platformVersion=6.0, automationName=Appium, platformName=Android, deviceName=Automation, version=6.0, optionalIntentArguments=--es appium_config "{"useTimeSelection":false,"disableBirthday":true}", fullReset=true}, newCommandTimeout=4000, platformVersion=6.0.1, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, automationName=Appium, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Android, optionalIntentArguments=--es appium_config "{"useTimeSelection":false,"disableBirthday":true}"}]
Session ID: 30270d0f-8594-4ead-b5b6-56dfeee37f44

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:51)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.close(RemoteWebDriver.java:521)
    at foundation.AppiumTestTest.afterM(AppiumTestTest.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:712)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:746)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)
```

Comment: I tried to use (alwaysRun = true)
Didn't helped.

Comment: you would need to show us the complete stacktrace so that we can understand the nature of your failures.

Comment: i think your problem is, as you used driver.quit in after method, so after the execution of first testcase, your driver is not initialized again. try to initialize driver only once in beforeclass and quit this driver in aftertest or afterclass.

Answer (score 1):

Move `driver = DesiredCapabilitiesSetup.startAppiumServer...` to `@BeforeMethod`. Also if you want to use different drivers for tests you will have to add parametrization (e.g. `@BeforeMethod` for group, `@DataProvider` or `@Facotry`).

Comment: But if i have 2 different @Test which should have different set up under same class? 
Basically single flow got tested against 2 similar apps but some configurations are different.

Comment: The simplest one in your case is to use 'groups' - mark your tests with two groups and create '@BeforeMethod' for each one.